# Why the case class returns a dataframe in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Below just take Union as an example.

I am reading the spark sql source code, and got stucken on this code, which is in the [DataFrame.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala)

```
def unionAll(other: DataFrame): DataFrame = Union(logicalPlan, other.logicalPlan)
```

and the Union is a case class which defined like this

```
case class Union(left: LogicalPlan, right: LogicalPlan) extends BinaryNode {...}
```

I'm confused, how can the result be treat as a instance of DataFrame type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if something is not clear in Scala it has to be an `implicit`. First lets take a look at the [`BinaryNode` node definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan.scala#L303):

```
abstract class BinaryNode extends LogicalPlan
```

Since `LogicalPlan` combined with `SQLContext` [is the only thing required to create a `DataFrame`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L128) it looks like a good place for a conversion. And [here it is](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L153):

```
@inline private implicit def logicalPlanToDataFrame(logicalPlan: LogicalPlan): 
    DataFrame = {
  new DataFrame(sqlContext, logicalPlan)
}
```

Actually this conversion has been removed in 1.6.0 by [SPARK-11513](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11513) with a following description:

> DataFrame has an internal implicit conversion that turns a LogicalPlan into a DataFrame. This has been fairly confusing to a few new contributors. Since it doesn't buy us much, we should just remove that implicit conversion.

Comment: you are rocked. I am a newbie to scala and spark, and your answer are perfectly answered my question. Thanks a lot.